# Node.js ffi access to dll

Tags: node.js, ffi

We have a C# wrapper to a dll that I'd like to convert over to a node.js wrapper for enhancements.  I can't seem to get the irSAInitialize function to return a handle or successful response.  This is my first attempt at using ffi, but believe I have everything setup correctly (another function in the dll seems to work).

Here is the simple POC code I have which attempts to initialize then log the results.

```
var ffi = require('ffi');
var ref = require('ref');

var intPtr = ref.refType('long');
var dllPath = "O:\\ApiBin\\";
var dllFile = dllPath + "irApiSA.dll";
var randConnect = ffi.Library(dllFile, {
    'irSAInitialize': ['int', ['string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', intPtr]],
    'irUnInitialize': ['int', []]
});

var handleOut = ref.alloc('long');
var a=b=c=d=e=f="";

var result = randConnect.irSAInitialize(a, b, c, d, e, f, handleOut);
console.log("Init Result: " + result);
handle = handleOut.deref();
console.log("Init Handle: " + handle);

var uninitResult = randConnect.irUnInitialize();
console.log("Uninit Result: " + uninitResult);
```

And here are the results I see.  Notice the uninit function seems to return successfully (result 1), so it seems to have proper communication with the DLL.

```
Init Result: 0
Init Handle: 0
Uninit Result: 1
```

Here is the relevant part of the .h for reference

```
typedef long IR_HANDLE;
typedef enum {IR_FAILURE_CODE = 0, IR_SUCCESS_CODE = 1} IR_ERROR_CODE;

IR_DECL_SPEC IR_ERROR_CODE irSAInitialize                   (const char *szDARouterFilePath, const char *szDADataFilePath, const char *szRouterFilePath, const char *szMapFilePath, const char *szAdminFilePath, const char *szDataFilePath, IR_HANDLE *pirHandle);
```

Also for reference, here are the snippets of C# code that works in the existing solution

```
[DllImport("irApiSA.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int irSAInitialize(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e, String f, ref int handle);
...
char[] temp = new char[256];
String s = new String(temp);
int result = irSAInitialize(s, s, s, s, s, s, ref handle);
```

I've tried many variations of using int vs long, string vs buffer, etc... no luck.  Any help or suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but found that I'm able to run this successfully if I run it with administrative privileges.  A few other notes for this particular dll:

- It is 32 bit so you must be running 32 bit Node.js
- Path environment variable must include path the the DLL (so it can find it's dependencies)

Hope this saves someone else hours of pain!